# Как в лейбл вывести числа double

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

Мне нужно выводить числа типа double полностью они приходят уже в формате String^

```
System::Void MyForm::button3_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    label1->Text = equals(conv(System::Convert::ToString(label2->Text)), conv(System::Convert::ToString(label1->Text)));
}
```

Если бы допустим я это выводил в консоль, то воспользовался бы `cout << setprecision(5) << a;`
Вот представляю функции, чтобы было более понятно

```
   std::string MyForm::conv(String^ str)
{
    std::string s;
    s = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(str);
    return s;
}
```

```
String^ MyForm::equals(std::string str1, std::string str2)
{
    if (str1 == "")
        return "DUMB";
    if (str1 == "DUMB")
        return "DUMB";
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string str;
    String^ str3;
    double first;
    double second;
    double result;
    char* arr = new char[str1.length()];
    char* arr1 = new char[str2.length()];
    char sym;
    strcpy(arr, str1.c_str());
    strcpy(arr1, str2.c_str());
    sym = arr[str1.length() - 1];
    for (int a = 0; a < str1.length()-1; a++)
    {
        if (arr[a] == ',')
            ss << '.';
        else
            ss << arr[a];
    }
    ss >> first;
    ss.clear();
    for (int a = 0; a < str2.length(); a++)
    {
        if (arr1[a] == ',')
            ss << '.';
        else
            ss << arr1[a];
    }
    ss >> second;
    ss.clear();
    switch (sym)
    {
    case '+' :
        result = first + second;
        break;
    case '-':
        result = first - second;
        break;
    case 'x':
        result = first * second;
        break;
    case '/':
        result = first / second;
        break;
    }
    ss << result;
    ss >> str;
    ss.clear();
    str3 = gcnew System::String(str.c_str());
    str = "";
    return str3;
}
```

Comment: Жуть! Зачем вы смешали в одном проекте C, C++ и C++/CLI?

Comment: Если вы хотите освоить .NET и WinForms, то пишите на C#, забудьте про C++/CLI.

Comment: Если вы хотите освоить C++, то не касайтесь .NET, WinForms, CLR. И откажитесь на время от Visual Studio (она провоцирует на .net и winforms), возьмите какую-нибудь другую IDE.

Comment: [Format types in .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types). И по ссылкам смотрите Standard и Custom numeric format strings.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov На C++/CLI я делаю графические элементы, на C++ пишу логику, C я там не использовал. C# мне не нравится, если бы я искал совета на каком языке мне писать я бы так и сформулировал свой вопрос. Visual studio я открыл впервые для написания этого проекта, до этого всегда работал в среде Code::Blocks, был опыт создания приложения на  wxWidgets

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov можете ли вы конкретно на моём примере написать, как использовать это форматирование? А то там всё для C#, который я не знаю

Comment: `char*` и `strcpy` - это, по сути, C. Без этого прекрасно можно обойтись, имея `std::string`.

Comment: Вывести число: `label->Text = num.ToString("...");`, где num - число (double), а в кавычках - нужный формат.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну в функцию мне уже приходит не число, а строка, поэтому я 
решил в функции equals не передаю строку через stringstream, а преобразовывать способов, который Вы описали выше. Спасибо за помощь!